# Object not being parsed in ejs file

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm building a movie database with MongoDB, node.js, and express. I have two routes currently, one that renders a page that displays all of the movies in the database, and another that displays information for an individual movie. The problem is when rendering the page for each individual movie with ejs, I am not able to parse the object that is passed, which holds things like the title, the year, and a few arrays of images.

When rendering the all movies page, I am able to parse the object and display it with ejs. So I am not sure what the difference between the two routes is.

**Schema for Movie**

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
date: String,
production: String,
cast: String,
remarks: String,
lobbyCards: Array,
filmStills: [
    {
        url: String,
        caption: String
    }
],
behindStills: [
    {
        url: String,
        caption: String
    }
],
advertising: [
    {
        url: String,
        caption: String
    }
]
```

});

Here are the two routes:

**All Movies**

```
app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
movie.find({}, (err, movies) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render('movies', { movies: movies });

        // console.log(movies);
    }
});
```

});

**Individual Movie**

```
app.get('/movies/:name', (req, res) => {
movie.find({ name: req.params.name }, (err, movieData) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render('show', { movieData: movieData });
    }
});
```

});

If I console.log(movieData) it is logged as an array.

[All Films Ejs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BHCS.png)

[Individual Film Ejs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaZHT.png)

This is what renders from the All films page
[All films](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BZGB.png)

This is what renders from the Individual Film Page
[Individual film](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC1KH.png)

Comment: Inside de else and before the res.render... if you console.log movieData the data is showed?

Comment: Yes, it console.logs the whole object inside an array

Comment: Can you add the schema definition for `Movie`?

Comment: @eol schema is now added to the question

Comment: res.render('movies/show', { movieData: movieData }); ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a single document from the db, you probably want to use:

```
movie.findOne({ name: req.params.name }, (err, movieData) => { ... }
```

With `.find()` an array is returned even when only one document matches the query which is why the movie object cannot be displayed in your ejs.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the perfect solution.